# How to get weather via cmd in Windows 8.1 using cURL?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, curl, weather

How do I get weather results using `cURL`, assigning a variable to it for later use? Something like:

```bat
# This doesn't work and is only a reference for what I want:

  set mytemperature= curl www.yahoo.com/(mycity)/weather.temperature  
  echo %mytemperature%
```

Comment: Do you mean with or without installing additional software? In Windows 10 you could use curl command but Windows 8 doesn't come with curl by default.

Comment: @RicardoBohner I can definitely do that. You can answer please.

Comment: @RicardoBohner I installed cURL and edited the question. Thanks for nudging in the right direction.

Comment: More than likely any commercial internet site hosting this info will require you to use some sort of API to access their data/services programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

---

To save descriptions and temperature in a variable from your `.bat` file, also removing characters `┬░` (hex: `[0xB0 and 0xC2`) from `wttr.in` output `London: +13┬░C` and getting back the degree sign [`º`]:

- ```bat
  @echo off 

  cd /d "%~dp0" && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

  >nul chcp 437 && set /p "_city=Please, enter some location, city, an attraction: " 
  for /f "delims= " %%d in ('forFiles /p "." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0xF8"')do set "_o=%%~d"

  for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('^<con: curl https://wttr.in/%_city: =+%^?format^=%%l:+%%t\n -s
  ')do for /f %%T in ('^<con: cmd /u /c "echo\%%~i"^<nul^|find/v "%_o%"^|findstr /v ^,"
  ')do set "_dt=!_dt!%%~T"

  set "_description_temperature=!_dt::=: !" && call echo\!_description_temperature:+=!!_o!C

  timeout -1 & endlocal & goto :eof
  ```

  Outputs: **`London: +13°C`**

  ```bat
  rem :: char       hex code
  rem ::  ░    ==   0xB0   // removed in loop
  rem ::  ┬    ==   0xC2   // removed in loop
  rem ::  °    ==   0xF8   // set _description_temperature=!_dt::=: !!_o!
  ```

---

---

Old:

- PowerShell: you can use the solution from [**@igor_chubin**](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/08/24/get-weather-report-using-powershell)

  ```bat
  (curl http://wttr.in/riodejaneiro -UserAgent "curl" ).Content
  ```

  or

  ```bat
  powershell -nop -c "(curl http://wttr.in/riodejaneiro -UserAgent "curl" ).Content"
  ```
- Batch File: when using whiteout, provide some location [**`curl http://wttr.in`**], else your current location will be assumed to display the data:

  ```bat
  @echo off && title <nul && title %~nx0 && mode 128,45

  powershell -nop -c "(curl http://wttr.in/riodejaneiro -UserAgent "curl" ).Content"
  ```
- Cmd:

  ```bat
  set _temp=cmd /a /v /c "curl wttr.in/RioDeJaneiro?format=^%t --silent"

  %_temp%
  ```

---

Define outputs:

- ```bat
  $ curl wttr.in/London?format=%l:+%t\n 
    London: +13°C
  ```

  - **To specify your own custom output format, use the special [%-notation](https://github.com/chubin/wttr.in/blob/master/README.md):**

    ```bat
    c    Weather condition,
    C    Weather condition textual name,
    h    Humidity,
    t    Temperature (Actual),
    f    Temperature (Feels Like),
    w    Wind,
    l    Location,
    m    Moonphase ,
    M    Moonday,
    p    precipitation (mm),
    P    pressure (hPa),
    D    Dawn*,
    S    Sunrise*,
    z    Zenith*,
    s    Sunset*,
    d    Dusk*.

      (*times are shown in the local timezone)
    ```

    ```bat
    $ curl wttr.in/London?format=3
      London: ⛅️ +7⁰C

    $ curl wttr.in/London?format="%l:+%c+%t\n"
      London: ⛅️ +7⁰C
    ```
- If you want to know the name of one of the coldest permanently inhabited locales on the planet and get the weather there:

  ```bat
  curl wttr.in/*
  ```

Comment: But how do I set the value of Temp./Weather to a Variable?

Comment: @batchcoding____s see edit...

Answer (score 5):

**Get the temperature into a variable:**

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > nul
::Put your city here:
set City=Rio de Janeiro

set City_=%City: =-%
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('curl --silent wttr.in/%City_%?format^=%%t') do set "CTemperature=%%a"
set CTemperature=%CTemperature:+=%
set CTemperature=%CTemperature:~0,-3%
echo The current temperature in %City% is %CTemperature% º Celcios
echo.
pause
```

**Get temperature and weather description into variables:**

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > nul
::Put your city here:
set City=Rio de Janeiro

set City_=%City: =-%
for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('curl --silent wttr.in/%City_%?format^=%%t') do set "CTemperature=%%a"
set CTemperature=%CTemperature:+=%
set CTemperature=%CTemperature:~0,-3%
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4*" %%a in ('curl --silent wttr.in/%City_%?0') do set "Description=%%a %%b"& goto :Next
:Next
echo.
echo The current temperature in %City% is %CTemperature% º Celcios "%Description%"
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Works like a Charm! Just can we also get the weather in a variable - like Cloudy or Raining?

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: To get a list of the options you can use in this website you can go to http://wttr.in/:help

Answer (score 1):

> `curl wttr.in/Mumbai`

for knowing temperature for few day

just use the curl command and your city name and get weather report

this is weather report for city of MUMBAI:
[image: Image of cmd for weather of Mumbai]